# Google App Engine Tutorial, 403 Forbidden: BadAuthentication on upload data

Tags: android, google-app-engine, backend, http-status-code-403

I am following the guide at: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/ using Android Studio.

I have followed the tutorial from beginning up to 'Populate the datastore with data'.

I navigated to the correct directory, successfully ran `gcloud auth login` from terminal, and logged in via the browser which was created. I then attempted to run the first command given:

```
/home/XXXX/google_appengine/appcfg.py upload_data --config_file bulkloader.yaml --url=http://mobileassistant-1026/remote_api --filename places.csv --kind=Place -e XXXXXXX@gmail.com
```

where the XXXXs are my username and email address respectively.

The terminal returns (with me entering the password half way):

```
12:25 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20150805.122507
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Password for XXXXXXX@gmail.com: 
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
403 Forbidden: BadAuthentication
--- end server output ---
```

Does anybody know how to get past this error?

I am completely new to App Engine, and backends in general, so please assume no knowledge in any answers!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue due to 2-step verification for your gmail account.
Please add another member(gmail)as owner in your console.developers.google.com project and try it will work...as i did same thing and it worked for me.